# My email address is constantly listed by SORBS and barracudacentral, how can I remove my email definitly from those services?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, email-client, email-filter

I have removed the affected IPs several times from SORBS and BarracudaCentral. But is still listing me through different IPs. It's quite annoying to remove my IP several times per month. The curious thing is that my email address(job email) is the only one affected in the company(30 employees). I only send email to my colleagues and to a few customers (they reply me)

Check out a common message that I'm receiving:
SMTP error from remote server after transfer of mail text:
host mail.enterprise-ireland.com[137.191.232.73]:
554 Service unavailable; Client host [mout.perfora.net] blocked using
Barracuda Reputation;
http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?r=1&ip=189.3.231.109

Have you got any permanent solution to deal with this issue? I'll appreciate so much.

Answer (score 0):

That IP is not connected to your email address directly. It is rather the outgoing / smtp IP of your internet service provider's mail server. You can see that over here:
http://www.whois.com/whois/189.3.231.109

I would suggest reporting this to them as soon as possible. Delisting it yourself is not going to solve anything on the long term.

You can check the real-time blocklists that have listed that IP here:
http://multirbl.valli.org/

They (the isp) will have to determine the cause of the spam, disable or remove it and only then the IP will be delisted, it can take a few days.